# Setting data-driven symbol levels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, atlas, rendering

How to drive symbol levels based on an attribute or data element such as area in a QGIS layer? How to set data-driven rendering order?

We have a set of boundaries that include very large and very small sizes.
Manually setting the symbol level to the known order is ok for a single map, but when dozens of maps are to be made (atlas), driving the symbol levels based on an attribute or data driven expression would be valuable.

Comment: As symbol layers, when activated, are drawn in order for the whole layer, I can't really understand how to drive them with a data element such as area.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is <strike>Yes</strike> **No**.

**EDIT**

As @Babel pointed it out to me, Symbol levels are a vector layer symbology option to choose the order of symbol layers, [see here the official documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#symbol-levels).

[image: QGIS Symbol levels]

So the answer is no, see this QGIS Project GitHub issue, opened in 2013, still open : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/17276.

---

Here the old answer where I believed that the symbol level was the size of the outline for boundaries for example :

- For a standard order: if you want your border width to go from 1 to 5, with 5 features, each feature will have an integer width. I insist on the *standard* because if you have 4 small features and 1 big, the biggest of the 4 small features will have a width of 4.

Here is the expression:

```sql
with_variable('sorted_array_by_area', array_agg($id, order_by:=$area),
array_find(@sorted_array_by_area, $id) / array_length(@sorted_array_by_area)
)
```

The result here is a percentage going from 1/features count to 1.
You can reverse this percentage by substracting the expression from 1:

```sql
with_variable('sorted_array_by_area', array_agg($id, order_by:=$area),
(1 - array_find(@sorted_array_by_area, $id) / array_length(@sorted_array_by_area))
)
```

You can adjust the maximum value by multiplying it by this maximum value.

- For a non-standard order, value dependent: in the previous example, the 4 smallest features will have small values and the big one the max.

Here is the expression:

```sql
with_variable('area_array', array_agg($area),
($area - array_min(@area_array)) / (array_max(@area_array) - array_min(@area_array))
)
```

As with the standard expression, as it returns a percentage, you can reverse the order with `1 - expression`.

And if you want to set a maximum value: `expression * maximum_value`

---

**S**̲u̲m̲m̲a̲r̲y̲ **T**̲a̲b̲l̲e̲

| Area value : | 2 | 3 | 4 | 7 | 18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Index in a sorted array by area | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| Standard Method : <kbd>index / array length</kbd> | 1 / 5 = 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.6 | 0.8 | 1 |
| Standard Method with a maximum value of 5 | 0.2 * 5 = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| Non-Standard Method : <kbd>(area - min area) / (max area - min area)</kbd> | 0 | (3 - 2) / (18 - 2) = 0.0625 | 0.125 | 0.3125 | 1 |
| Non-Standard Method with a maximum value of 5 | 0 | 0.3125 | 0.375 | 1.25 | 5 |

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers the question. I don't think the question is about border width, but about rendering order of symbol layers. In my symbol levels dialog, I can't find any place where I could introduce any expression, see this screeshot of several buffers (each a separate symbol layer created with Geometry generator) around a polygon: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pgF5.png - fields accept only integer numbers as inputs, no decimals, no characters. See also https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html?#symbol-levels

Comment: Oh ... I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Never mind: still a great answer (even if to another question...) ;-)

Comment: The question is about rendering order of symbol layers. Babel understood this question correctly.

Comment: I answered in the first part of the answer, there is, for the moment, no solution. I will take a look at PyQGIS, maybe the API can order symbol layers.

Comment: @J.Monticolo I expected data-driven symbol rendering levels to work only within a single layer, so the answer of RafDouglas was good enough. But also I voted up your answer. Thank you.

Comment: @KVO: ok, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Use `Control feature rendering order`*?**

while not at the same technical depth as [@J. Monicolo's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/411333/142513), a **workaround** (which is not *exactly* as sporting a full fledge feature-based `Symbol levels`), is to enable `Control feature rendering order`, which support cascading rules:

[image]

This of course **only** takes in consideration **features within the same layer**, but could be useful for some users.